# Resolving error when merging dataframes on two columns

Tags: pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes (D1 & R1) on two columns (Date & Symbol) but I'm receiving this error `"You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"`.

I've been using pd.merge and I've tried different dtypes. I don't want to concatenate these because I just want to add D1 to the right side of R1.

```
D2 = pd.merge(D1, R2, on=['Date','Symbol'])

D1.dtypes()
Date              object
Symbol            object
High             float64
Low              float64
Open             float64
Close            float64
Volume           float64
Adj Close        float64
pct_change_1D    float64
Symbol_above      object
NE                  bool

R1.dtypes()
gvkey             int64
datadate          int64
fyearq            int64
fqtr              int64
indfmt           object
consol           object
popsrc           object
datafmt          object
tic              object
curcdq           object
datacqtr         object
datafqtr         object
rdq               int64
costat           object
ipodate         float64
Report_Today      int64
Symbol           object
Date              int64
```

Ideally, the columns not in the index of R1 (gvkey - Report_Today) will be on the right side of the columns in D1.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Can you please share your code and sample data to reproduce your scenario at our end to help you?

Comment: Can you pd.to_datime(R1['Date']) and pd.to_datetime(D1['Date'])?

Answer (score 2):

In your description of DataFrames we can see,
In D1 DataFrame column Date has type "object"
In R1 DataFrame column Date has type "int64".

Make types of these columns the same and everything will be OK.